# How to solve an irrational inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to solve the following inequality:

$$\sqrt{1-2x} < \sqrt{4 - x}$$

I don't understand why "$(1-2x)$ have to be $\ge  0$". If it was the rule for numbers inside a square root, I was checking whether we had to solve for "$4-x\ge 0$" as well.

Comment: Square both sides of the inequality.

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.

Comment: I'm new. I'm really sorry. Thanks for reminding ^^

Comment: $1-2x$ has to be $\geq 0$ because that is when the square root is defined. If it is $< 0$, you get a negative number inside a square root, which is undefined

Comment: So then, would it also work if I have 4−x≥0? That would give me a different answer though. Not 1/2 but x≤4 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-2x}&<\sqrt{4-x} \\
\left(\sqrt{1-2x}\right)^2&<\left(\sqrt{4-x}\right)^2 \\
1-2x&<4-x \\
-x&<3 \\
x&>-3 \\
\end{align}
$$
Remember the domain: $x\leq\frac 12$. Any $x$ greater than $\frac 12$ is not defined. Therefore the answer is:
$$-3<x\leq \frac 12$$

You can solve this graphically as well.
$$\sqrt{1-2x}<\sqrt{4-x}$$
$$\implies \sqrt{1-2x}-\sqrt{4-x}<0$$
I will now graph the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-2x}-\sqrt{4-x}$

[image]

The solution to the inequality are the values less than $0$. We can see that these values are in the region $-3<x\leq \frac 12$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all notice that for the L.H.S. to make sense, we should have $$x \le \frac{1}{2} $$ and for the R.H.S, we should have $$x \le {4} $$ now taking the square of both sides, we get $$1 - 2x < 4 - x $$ the above inequalities could be summarized as $$ - 3 < x \le \frac{1}{2} $$